# How to send an e-mail to a user selected in a webform via a user reference field?

Tags: 7, users, rules, webforms, emails

I have a webform, that the HR use. I have a form component of the users, that is a user reference field.

I would like to use [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) to send an e-mail notification to the selected user.

If I use: `[data:{component}-display]`, then after the username [1] appears, that refers to the link to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your question doesn't say so (yet), I'm assuming (as per your "*... I have a form component of the users, that is a user reference field...*") that you're also using the [Webform References](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_references) module. Some details about that module (from its project page):

> Provides a webform component that can reference a node/term/user in [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). It provides "Select List", "Autocomplete", "Checkbox" and "Radio" as widget.

If you also have the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module enabled, then it is possible to create a rule (using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)), which does what you're asking for. Here is an export of a rule that will send an eMail to the eMail Id of the referenced user:

```
{ "rules_email_submitted_webform_to_referenced_user" : {
    "LABEL" : "eMail submitted webform to referenced user",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "webform_rules", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "webform_has_id" : {
          "form_id" : [ "form_id" ],
          "selected_webform" : { "value" : { "webform-client-form-191" : "webform-client-form-191" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "The webform submitted contains the field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_userref-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_userref-value-raw]\u0022." } },
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "[data:demoform_userref-value-raw]" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "referenced_user_txt" : "Referenced user" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_convert" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "integer", "value" : [ "referenced-user-txt" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "conversion_result" : { "referenced_user_uid" : "Referenced User Uid" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_fetch" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "user", "id" : [ "referenced-user-uid" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "user_fetched" : "Fetched user" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "referenced_user_txt: [referenced-user-txt:value] AND referenced_user_uid: [referenced-user-uid:value] AND\r\n\r\nUser fetched: uid=[user-fetched:uid] name=[user-fetched:name] mail=[user-fetched:mail]" } },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "user-fetched:mail" ],
          "subject" : "Hey [user-fetched:name] you have new mail ...",
          "message" : "The webform submitted contains these fields:\r\n\u003C\/ul\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003Ethe field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_title-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_title-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003E the field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_text-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_text-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003E the field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_number-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_number-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003E the field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_option-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_option-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003C\/ul\u003E",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about this rule (prior to trying to import this rule in your own site, make sure to adapt (rename) what's needed to fit your case):

- The form ID I'm using is `191`.
- All form components have machine names starting with `demoform`.
- The machine name of the reference user is `demoform_userref`.

The Rules Event and Rules Condition should be straight forward, though the actual Rules *magic* happens in the Rules Actions:

1. <kbd>Show a message</kbd> on the site (just for demo purposes).
2. <kbd>Add a **text** variable</kbd> (to capture "some" webform data about the selected user, has to be text ...).
3. <kbd>Convert a variable</kbd> from a **text** to an **integer** variable (we need an integer for the next Rules Action, text won't work ...).
4. <kbd>Fetch an entity by ID</kbd> (the integer variable, to fetch the user with that ID).
5. <kbd>Show a message</kbd> on the site (just for demo purposes).
6. <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd> (**to** the eMail ID from the *fetched user*).

#### Demo

After submitting my demoform, the messages shown are like so:

```
The webform submitted contains the field labeled "User" which has value "123".
referenced_user_txt: 123 AND referenced_user_uid: 123 AND User fetched: uid=123 name=Pierre.Vriens mail=pierre.vriens@somewhere.com
```

Moreover, an eMail got delivered to pierre.vriens@somewhere.com ...

*Subject*:

```
  Hey Pierre.Vriens you have new mail ...
```

*Message*:

```
  The webform submitted contains these fields:
   * the field labeled "Title" which has value "Some title".
   * the field labeled "Text" which has value "Some text".
   * the field labeled "Number" which has value "7".
   * the field labeled "Option" which has value "C".
```